# what does Stop Inheriting Permissions for a SharePoint list do?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to allow the anonymous user to create the item in the list. For that I have to stop inheriting permissions for the particular list and then I can provide the access to the anonymous user to create the item. Now my query is if I am doing "Stop Inheriting Permissions" then will it effect only that particular list or will it effect all other lists available in the site. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop Inheriting Permissions always affect only current SharePoint Item (web, list, item, folder) on which is set, and its children sub-items which inheriting permisisons from parent.

If you set new permissions on list or library. Permissions are set only for this list or library. For sub-items permissions will be inherited (if there is no stopped inheriting).

Comment: So permission settings for other lists will not get effected?

Comment: No, 
* if other lists inheriting permissions for web you can affect these permissions only on web
* if other lists has unique permissions too you can affect these permissions only on this list